# Why variables of function declared outside through "." accessible only through "." inside the function?

Tags: javascript

I initialized a variable of function through "." outside the function. Regarding closure rule, it should be set inside the function scope and after execution should be gone. But

1. Why after calling the function variable still exists?
2. Why can I access inside a function only through "."?

I initialized variable outside of the function through "." like f1.a = "any variable".

1. I checked if the variable of function initialized outside is accessible inside a function without ".": 
   I tried to get access to the variable inside the function. It seems if I get access to the variable by itself without "." it gives me an error "variable is not defined".
2. I checked if the variable of function initialized outside will be gone after function execution:
   I call function and check if the value of the variable after execution is still available. Yes, it was still there.

```
f1.a = "any variable";
function f1(){
    (function()
    {
        console.log(a);
    }())  // a is not defined
}
f1();
console.log(f1.a);                  // after f1(), f1.a still exist
```

1. I expected variable "a" visible by itself inside the "f1" since I initialized inside the function scope f1.a = "any variable", but I can get access only with "."
2. I expected variable "a" will be gone after execution f1(), but it still exists

Comment: The symbol `a` by itself does not implicitly resolve to the context of the function object; that basically never happens in JavaScript (except for the `with` statement which is almost never used because it's terrible).

Comment: In other words, *Regarding closure rule, it should be set inside the function scope and after execution should be gone.* is completely wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean why we can see f1.a inside and outside of the scope

Comment: Because `f1` is just an object, and when you put a property on an object you can "see" it from anywhere.

Comment: so f1 could be the same time object and function?

Comment: You seem to assume that `f1.a` is the same as `var a` inside the function. That entire assumption is incorrect - `f1` is just a function object, it has nothing to do with scope when you assign properties to it.

Comment: @Gold all functions are objects, and can be treated as such.

Comment: `.a` is not a variable, it's an object property. They are very different from `var a`-declared variables, for which scoping rules apply and which would be visible inside the function. (That said, the variable `f1` is visible inside the function, and you could access the `f1.a` property there).

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you need to understand to get a clear idea of what's happening here. First, JavaScript hoists function definitions to the top of the file.

Knowing that, you could imagine your code is something like this once JavaScript interprets it:

```
var f1 = function (){
    (function()
    {
        console.log(a);
    }())  // a is not defined
}

f1.a = "any variable"

f1();
console.log(f1.a);
```

Secondly, in your first `console.log(a)` you are referencing a variable `a` which was never declared. If you change that to `console.log(f1.a)` you'll see the value of `f1.a` as expected.

It's also not clear why you are using an immediately invoked function inside of your `f1` function. It makes analyzing this code even more complex. It seems like you are trying to get a better understanding of how closures work? But for closures you should be interested in variables declared inside of `f1`, rather than properties of `f1`. For example, something like this.

```
f1 = function (){
 var a = 'something'
    return function()
    {
        console.log(a);
    }
}

var closure = f1();
// f1 is finished running here.
closure(); // closure still has access to f1's variable.
```

I think the three areas you could learn more about to understand the code above are 1. Scope and especially hoisting 2. Objects, `this` and object properties and 3. Closures.